# Wifi constantly disconnecting in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, iwlwifi

I know there are ten million wifi questions, but I can't seem to find any that fix my problem, and the line between Ubuntu and returning to Windows kind of hinges on resolving this issue. So, apologies for the duplicate, but it's a last ditch effort.

Similarly to others, my wifi has an incredibly weak signal, disconnects frequently, and seems to have a perfectly fine connection if I disconnect and immediately reconnect, just for a moment.

This is the output for `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (3) I218-V (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev e3)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59)
```

Output for `lshw -C network`:

```
 *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (3) I218-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: enp0s25
       version: 03
       serial: 68:f7:28:f6:68:ca
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.2-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:48 memory:f1200000-f121ffff memory:f123e000-f123efff ioport:3080(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7265
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 59
       serial: 5c:e0:c5:b2:bc:ae
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.8.0-52-generic firmware=22.391740.0 ip=192.168.1.31 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:47 memory:f1000000-f1001fff
```

EDIT: output for `dmesg`:

```
[ 3758.071805] wlp3s0: associated
[ 3878.074757] wlp3s0: disconnect from AP ac:9e:17:95:dd:e8 for new auth to ac:9e:17:93:bb:20
[ 3878.094362] wlp3s0: authenticate with ac:9e:17:93:bb:20
[ 3878.098822] wlp3s0: send auth to ac:9e:17:93:bb:20 (try 1/3)
[ 3878.100825] wlp3s0: authenticated
[ 3878.103927] wlp3s0: associate with ac:9e:17:93:bb:20 (try 1/3)
[ 3878.111295] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from ac:9e:17:93:bb:20 (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=7)
[ 3878.112788] wlp3s0: associated
[ 3997.968277] wlp3s0: disconnect from AP ac:9e:17:93:bb:20 for new auth to ac:9e:17:95:dd:e8
[ 3997.978354] wlp3s0: authenticate with ac:9e:17:95:dd:e8
[ 3997.982613] wlp3s0: send auth to ac:9e:17:95:dd:e8 (try 1/3)
[ 3997.986793] wlp3s0: authenticated
[ 3997.991208] wlp3s0: associate with ac:9e:17:95:dd:e8 (try 1/3)
[ 3997.995097] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from ac:9e:17:95:dd:e8 (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=2)
[ 3997.996529] wlp3s0: associated
[ 4108.620415] perf: interrupt took too long (3237 > 3218), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 61750
```

I forget if other commands are relevant so let me know in the comments and I'll edit.

Thanks very much for any help. I really don't want to go back to Windows but I need working internet.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59369/discussion-on-question-by-snapcrack-wifi-constantly-disconnecting-in-16-04).